# Do I need to delete tmp files created by my java application?

Tags: java, temporary-files

I output several temporary files in my application to tmp directories but was wondering if it is best practise that I delete them on close or should I expect the host OS to handle this for me?

I am pretty new to Java, I can handle the delete but want to keep the application as multi-OS and Linux friendly as possible. I have tried to minimise file deletion if I don't need to do it.

This is the method I am using to output the tmp file:

```
 try {
                java.io.InputStream iss = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/nullpdf.pdf");
                byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(iss);
                iss.read(data);
                iss.close();
                String tempFile = "file";
                File temp = File.createTempFile(tempFile, ".pdf");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            nopathbrain = temp.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println(tempFile);
            System.out.println(nopathbrain);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("TEMP FILE NOT CREATED - ERROR ");
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`createTempFile()` only creates a new file with a unique name, but does not mark it for deletion. Use [`deleteOnExit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29) on the created file to achieve that. Then, if the JVM shuts down properly, the temporary files should be deleted.

*edit*:
Sample for creating a 'true' temporary file in java:

```
File temp = File.createTempFile("temporary-", ".pdf");
temp.deleteOnExit();
```

This will create a file in the default temporary folder with a unique random name (`temporary-{randomness}.pdf`) and delete it when the JVM exits.

This should be sufficient for programs with a short to medium run time (e.g. scripts, simple GUI applications) that do sth. and then exit. If the program runs longer or indefinitely (server application, a monitoring client, ...) and the JVM won't exit, this method may clog the temporary folder with files. In such a situation the temporary files should be deleted by the application, as soon as they are not needed anymore (see [`delete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29) or [`Files` helper class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#deleteIfExists%28java.nio.file.Path%29) in JDK7).

As Java already abstracts away OS specific file system details, both approaches are as portable as Java. To ensure interoperability have a look at the new [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) abstraction for file names in Java7.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I should use deleteOnExit() with the above method?  Thanks for your help